# Php curl incorrect download

Tags: php, xml, curl, download

I'm attempting to use Youtube's API to pull a list of video and display them. To do this, I need to curl their api and get the xml file returned, which I will then parse.

When I run the following curl function

```
function get_url_contents($url){
        $crl = curl_init();
        $timeout = 5;
        curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
        curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
        $ret = curl_exec($crl);
        curl_close($crl);
        return $ret;
}
```

against the url

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=Apple&orderby=relevance

The string that is saved is horribly screwed up. There are no < > tags, or half of the characters in most of it. It looks 100% different then if I view it in a browser.

I tried print, echo, and var dump and they all show it has completely different, which makes parsing it impossible.

How do I get the file properly from the server?

Answer (score 2):

It's working for me. I'm pretty sure that the file is returned without errors, but when you print it, the <> tags aren't showed. But if you look on the source code you can see them.

Try this, you can see it work:

```
$content = get_url_contents('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=Apple&orderby=relevance');
$xml = simplexml_load_string($content);
print_r($xml);
```

Comment: This shows the xml contents. Though its not very pretty :P. Thank you. I will look into the client library,and if that fails, rely on this to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Make use of the client library that Google provides, it'll make  your life easier.

http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_php.html